# Animation jumps as if it isn't interpolating properly

Tags: animation

I have an animation of a character walking, but the arms appear to jump back between two of the key frames, as if it isn't interpolating properly. It seems it should work fine when I look at the animation with interpolation set to constant.

If you watch carefully, you can see the arms jump

Bezier

[image]

Constant

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the problem. I had edited the rotations manually, and the w of one of the quaternions was negative, which seems to mess with the rotation. You can normalize it by setting the rotation to a format other than quaternion, then putting it back to quaternion.